# Debugging bibtex

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, errors

I am using a home-made thesis template available [here](http://www3.imperial.ac.uk/pls/portallive/docs/1/41657697.ZIP). The example is using `plain` bibliography style, I need `apa` though. After writing a few pages of introduction and changing the style, I get the following errors (one per cit

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \protect \astroncite 
                                {Akelof}{2003}
l.3 ...m[\protect\astroncite{Akelof}{2003}]{ake03}

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \protect \astroncite 
                                {Akerlof and Shiller}{2009}
l.9 ...ncite{Akerlof and Shiller}{2009}]{akeshi09}

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \protect \astroncite 
                                {Baker and Wurgler}{2006}
l.14 ...ncite{Baker and Wurgler}{2006}]{Baker2006}
```

etc.

How can I figure out what is wrong? Apa style works in all other documents, so I guess there must be something wrong with this style file...

Comment: Does this question help you [BibTeX compilation is corrupting myfiles](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/109555/35864) (found purely because of the use of `\astroncite`)?

Comment: If David Carlisle's advice does not help, a MWE would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Your bibtex style is assuming a matching latex style that defines some additional commands adding `\newcommand\astroncite[2]{???}` to your document preamble will probably get you going again, but you'd need to define it more appropriately (or find the original intended definition) (updated comment as I misread the structure in the error message originally)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, could you expand your comment a bit? What file should I be looking for? I could try to adapt the apa files from one of the standard document styles...

Comment: @Grzenio I don't know, I'm just going by the form of the error messgae you showed

Comment: `\astroncite` is in `apa.bst`....

Comment: It is indeed, but in my version of the file it is only called and not defined (apparently `astron.sty` defines it).

Answer (score 7):

Schoolboy error: I forgot to include `\usepackage{natbib}` in the document.